# The account you entered is not recognized. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator to add your account

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS 2013 and I am trying to customize a workitem template using the ProcessEditor form (I also tried to do the same using the editing and importing xml file),I am trying to add a "ReadlOnly" rule to a field only for some new TFS global group, so I added the new Group and after that I could see and select the newly added Group from the "For" dropdown but when I am trying to save the changes I always got the error "The account you entered is not recognized. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator to add your account" I googled the error and found a suggestion here http://www.databaseforum.info/30/943697.aspx that it may be a caching issue so I waited days for this and restarted the client and the TFS server machines but without any luck  although I can use old created groups without any issues however if I renamed one of these old groups then tried to use it I still got the same error message no matter I add the new groups as a member of any other group.

Comment: section after my change is **<FIELD name="Original Estimate" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate" type="Double" reportable="measure" formula="sum">
        <HELPTEXT>Initial value for Remaining Work - set once, when work begins</HELPTEXT>
        <WHEN field="System.State" value="Open">
          <REQUIRED />
        </WHEN>
  <READONLY not = "[Project]\Back End Team"/>
      </FIELD>**

Comment: Are you part of Project Administrators group on that team project? If not add yourself in Project Administrators group and try once..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was the service agent job that was responsible on syncing the AD changes with the tfs was stopped, everything worked fine when I started it

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your TFS admin  not have done any security changes (adding account or groups or permissions) for your account.

If not, you could try below  two possibilities to narrow down the issue:

Check if you had added a field that contained backslashes as values
   and TFS may interpreted it as user account. For example if your field
   contained a list of suggested values that looked like this: *Category
   1\Subcategory 1*

---

When you add a value such as

```
<TRANSITION from="Resolved" to="Complete" for="[project]AllTesters" not="[project]NewTesters">
</TRANSITION>
```

you should not extend the project to `[your project name]AllTesters`, should just use `[project]AllTesters`

For more detail info and ways, please refer below similar issues:

- [TF26204: The account you entered is not recognized](http://geekswithblogs.net/claraoscura/archive/2007/01/19/103973.aspx)
- [Experiment on Limit AssignedTo field of WIT to Team Members](http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2014/05/experiment-on-limit-assignedto-field-of_30.html)
- [Warnings TF26171 and TF26204 during WIT import](https://alfredmyersjr.wordpress.com/2009/02/10/warnings-tf26171-and-tf26204-during-wit-import-on-tfs-2005/)

Comment: I already added new TFS groups and played with the permissions so what should I check for?,Regarding the first possibility the only field I am changing in the workitem template xml file is the **team name** in `<READONLY not = ` section so the only change that causes the error is the new group name and when I change it to old group name the whole file imported successfully   and regarding the second possibility check my comment up,BTW if we don't add "\" as a separator between "[Project]" and "project name" we will get The value '[project]AllTesters' is invalid according to its datatype error

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing, I left it for couple of days and when I returned to it I found everything is working like a charm, I added now some new groups and couldn't see them so I guess I will wait some days for it to work!